# Javascript Timestamp to php - mysql timestamp type

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, timestamp

I send javascript timestamp data to php to add into mysql where I have type TIMESTAMP:

DATABASE - startTime type:

[image]

Now I try to send with ajax, timestamp from javascript `var startTime = Date.now();` to php where I need to tranform into TIMESTAMP type for mysql... so I try:

```
$datum = $app->request->post('startTime');
            $startTime = $datum->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //FIRST ATTEMP
            $startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datum); //SECOND TRY
```

Above I write two cases I try but both dont work... How I can transform it to correct format to add it to database...

*Probbaly you will ask why that when you have this in PHP, why get it with JS?
Becouse my app will use people in Autralia (and all ov r the world) and server is in EUROPE, so if I use php server time then I will make wrong date*

Comment: There should be no problem with relying on the PHP timestamp, as it can be easily converted to any time zone. Relying on the client time is not a good idea.

Comment: but how I can go what is the user timezone and what is the user correct time? with php

Comment: You can't read the time zone for sure, but you can gauge it based on the IP address location to make an educated guess. Yet the users should be enabled to change their time zone to the one they wish. You can use PHP libraries like the `DateTime` class to convert a timestamp to several time zones.

Comment: but is there any way (becouse my app is time tasks based) to get current user time witout JS, so just with php, and how?

Comment: It's not possible to get the users' time zones with PHP only. That's why the users should get a suggestion which they can either accept or decline and choose their right time zone. You should not rely on the client time as it can easily be manipulated by changing the system clock to a time in the past or future. Based on the time zone of your server and the choice of the user, you can provide correct date and time representations.

Comment: yes, that is the problem, changing the system time

Comment: User location based on IP is not something reliable, and if your application is time-based well work with your server time and transform in the client supposed time stamp format on the client side

Comment: please write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, you should make sure that the data in `$datum` is, in fact, a number:

```
$datum = $app->request->post('startTime');
if ( ! ctype_digit($datum)) {
    die('Invalid startTime!');
}
```

In Javascript, the `Date.now()` method returns a timestamp in *milliseconds*. The PHP functions that deal with dates and stuff like that use *seconds*, so you will have to turn it into seconds by dividing it with 1000 (milli means "thousandth"):

```
$datum = ($datum / 1000);
```

If you have already done this in the browser then you should ignore this, of course.

Before you insert it into your database you will have to turn the seconds into a format that MySQL understands. The `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. In PHP you can format it like this:

```
$datum = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datum);
```

Comment: thanks thats work. Also is there a way to without JS get user current time based on his timezone but just with php... I need to do that becouse JS time can be changed from users... and my app is time based

Comment: You can ask the user for their location, and then calculate their time based on that. There is, to my knowledge, no fool-proof way of getting a user's  timezone/time, except for just asking for it. You can use their IP address, and some web service, to find their location, but it has its own problems (they may be behind a proxy, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

The code below will convert JS date/time to MySQL format:

```
function SQLdate_now() {
    /* MySQL format */
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();
    var second = d.getSeconds();
    var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + ' ' +
        ((''+hour).length<2 ? '0' :'') + hour + ':' +
        ((''+minute).length<2 ? '0' :'') + minute + ':' +
        ((''+second).length<2 ? '0' :'') + second;
    return(output);
};
```

Comment: why that, I have timestamp , so timestamp from client from JS I send to php, where I need to transform just timestamp into TIMESTAMP type for mysql

Comment: I think Sverri's answer make more sense. I had a requirement to do the above in the past so I included that code.

Answer (score 1):

As we already pointed out in the comments, it is highly unrecommended to store client timestamps to a database due to vulnerabilities. A quite good compromise would be the time zone offset, which is accessible from javascript, to be saved into a cookie.

In JavaScript, you can read the offset in minutes like this:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Once saved to a cookie, it is also accessible from your PHP script and enables you to calculate the corret date and time strings.

Comment: Vulnerabilities? It is just an integer. If you validate or sanitize the data (which you should **always** do in any case) then there is no risk of anything. The only downside to using a client timestamp (*and timezone, for that matter*) is that it may be incorrect. There is not much one can do about that, short of actually asking the user if it is correct.

Comment: You are right, nevertheless I perceive saving client timestamps as a rather unpleasant solution.

Comment: Yeah, it is not ideal. It is better to ask the user for their location and then calculate the time based on that.